# AWK command replace third comma with new line or in other words make three columns for data

Tags: awk

Consider the following awk statement:

```
awk -v ORS=", " ' /^(Name|Exec|Icon)=/{sub(/Name=|Exec=|Icon=/,"");print}' /usr/share/applications/*.desktop
```

The output is  the "Name=/Exec=/Icon" of `.desktop` files of installed applications in /usr/share/application/ folder  in manjaro Linux distro, separated with commas and  with trailing comma:

`Qt Assistant, assistant, assistant, Avahi Zeroconf Browser, /usr/bin/avahi-discover, network-wired, kcmshell5 breezestyleconfig, preferences-desktop-theme, Breeze Widget Style, Avahi SSH Server Browser, /usr/bin/bssh, network-wired,`etc

The output that I want instead is:

```
Qt Assistant, assistant, assistant
Avahi Zeroconf Browser, /usr/bin/avahi-discover, network-wired
kcmshell5 breezestyleconfig, preferences-desktop-theme, Breeze Widget Style
Avahi SSH Server Browser, /usr/bin/bssh, network-wired
```

etc

without trailing comma.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what does `(Name|Exec|Icon)=` have to do with `one,two,three,four,...`. Update your question with code that should process your input and we'll help you fix it. Also, if  you expect to process files of data, can we assume the data is all "on one line" as shown in your example data?  Hal the battle in solving a problem is in being able to define correctly (-;, eh? Good luck.

Comment: will ***all*** lines contain 9 commas? and with no data after the 9th comma? if there could be lines with a different number of commas and/or data after the last comma, then please update the question to show some additional sample input lines as well as the expected results

Comment: It seems you have some misunderstandings about how awk works. Read the [awk tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) to improve that understanding. Good luck.

Comment: FYI `'/^(Name|Exec|Icon)=/{sub(/Name=|Exec=|Icon=/,"");print}'` = `'sub(/^(Name|Exec|Icon)=/,"")'`. So far you've shown us output but no input - we'd need to see both to be able to help you. Don't assume we know what `.desktop files of installed applications in /usr/share/application/ folder` means or have such files on our computers and even if we did they probably wouldn't be populated in exactly the way that yours are to produce that specific expected output in your question so we couldn't test a potential solution with them.

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: Are you strictly limited to `awk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't just print the fields when you see them as they may not appear in the order name,exec,icon in the desktop file.
2. Perhaps you meant to set `OFS=", "` rather than setting `ORS` ?

An approach that collects values, and then prints after each entire file has been read:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = "="
        OFS = ", "
    }

    {
        k = $1
        sub(/^[^=]*=/,"",$0)
    }

    k=="Name" { n[FILENAME] = $0 }
    k=="Exec" { e[FILENAME] = $0 }
    k=="Icon" { i[FILENAME] = $0 }

    FNR==1 {
        if(pf) print n[pf],e[pf],i[pf]
        pf = FILENAME
    }

    END {
        if(pf) print n[pf],e[pf],i[pf]
    }
' /usr/share/applications/*.desktop
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer .Correcting the syntax error in line 13, there is no output in terminal.

Comment: @cgiannakidis there was another typo. Should be `pf=FILENAME`

Comment: Yes.Thank you .This is what I was looking for.Last how can I run it in one line code in terminal ?

Comment: @cgiannakidis Save everything to a file and run `sh filename` ? Save the awk script to a file and run `awk -f scriptfile /paths/to/files/*` ?

Comment: Is it possible to limit the search  not to all file but only to the part ```[Desktop Entry]```

Comment: `awk '/^[ \t]*\[/{ok=/\[Desktop Entry\]/} !ok{next} ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'Qt Assistant, assistant, assistant, Avahi Zeroconf Browser, /usr/bin/avahi-discover, network-wired, kcmshell5 breezestyleconfig, preferences-desktop-theme, Breeze Widget Style, Avahi SSH Server Browser, /usr/bin/bssh, network-wired' |
```

---

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = (_ = "[ \t]*")(__ = "\n")("+")_
             RS = "^$"
       ___ = (_ = "[^" (OFS = ",") "]+, *")(_)_
              _ = "\1"
 } gsub(___,"&" _, $!(NF = NF)) \
   gsub(",[^," (_) "]*") _, __) sub("[" (_) "- ,]*$", __)'
```

---

```
Qt Assistant, assistant, assistant
Avahi Zeroconf Browser, /usr/bin/avahi-discover, network-wired
kcmshell5 breezestyleconfig, preferences-desktop-theme, Breeze Widget Style
Avahi SSH Server Browser, /usr/bin/bssh, network-wired
```